# Saving checkbox values causes issues with showing/hiding linked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, save

I have written a code to show or hide a picture based on the value of corresponding checkboxes. I was able to have the picture shown or hidden on reload if 'checked="checked"' is written into the checkbox.

I was able to write a code to save the value of the checkbox but then the picture is no longer tethered to the checked/unchecked value and changes with reload.

My end goal is to have the a checked checkbox to show the picture and unchecked checkbox to hide the picture and I need the value saved to allow the correct value to work on reload after a change has been made.

This is just a small snip of the overall code. The whole thing is a series of 64 checkboxes linked to 64 different pictures, which overlay a mapped background image.

I should also mention that this will ultimately be used for a SharePoint site, if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

(There is a link to jsfiddle demo at the bottom)

HTML:

```
<a href="home.aspx">
<p id="A1R1" style="left:146px;top:256px;position:absolute;z-index:inherit;" class="hidden">
<img id="A1R1" alt="A1R1" src="red.jpg" width="108" height="60" />
</p>
</a>
<a href="home2.aspx">
<p id="A2R2" style="left:273px;top:256px;position:absolute;z-index:inherit;" class="hidden">
<img id="A2R2" alt="A2R2" src="green.html" width="108" height="60" />
</p>
</a>

<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" style="width:165px">
<center>
<p style="font-size:25px">Show/Hide</p>
</center>
<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" style="width:150px">
<center>A1 Green/Red
<p>
</center>
<center>
<input type="checkbox" id="A1G" checked="checked" /> </center>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" style="width:150px">
<center>A2 Green/Red
<p>
</center>
<center>
<input type="checkbox" id="A2G" checked="checked" /> </center>
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
<center>
<input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()" />
<input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()" />
</center>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(i, $) {
var $A_1_G = $('#A1G'),
$A_1_R_1 = $('#A1R1');

var toggleMain = function() {
$A_1_R_1.slideToggle();
};
if ($A_1_G.is(':checked')) {
toggleMain();
}
$A_1_G.on('click', toggleMain);
})(document, jQuery);
(function(i, $) {
var $A_2_G = $('#A2G'),
$A_2_R_2 = $('#A2R2');

var toggleMain = function() {
$A_2_R_2.slideToggle();
};
if ($A_2_G.is(':checked')) {
toggleMain();
}
$A_2_G.on('click', toggleMain);
})(document, jQuery);
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function save() {
var checkbox = document.getElementById('A1G');
localStorage.setItem('A1G', checkbox.checked);

var checkbox = document.getElementById('A2G');
localStorage.setItem('A2G', checkbox.checked);
}

function load() {
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('A1G'));
document.getElementById("A1G").checked = checked;

var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('A2G'));
document.getElementById("A2G").checked = checked;
}

function wis() {
location.reload();
localStorage.clear()

}

load();
```

[Link to fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/trai2745/Lwxoeyyp/172/)

Comment: So you say, you have whole bunch of around 64 `checkboxes` right? Are you going to write this `localStorage.getItem` and `setItem` for all the `64` checkboxes? Also, are those `id`s given to `checkboxes` are unique right?

Comment: @piran Yes there will be the 64 boxes. They all have different Ids. (A1G-A8G, B1G-B8G...H1G-H8G). Right now my plan is to use localStorage for all 64 and all 64 pictures. If you need a visual of what I am doing, you can go [here](http://41.media.tumblr.com/2d5025d69e3780bde9202f53c4032730/tumblr_o459dbLlib1rxyg66o1_1280.jpg) to see the background photo. I will be overlaying [Red](http://40.media.tumblr.com/b920fbc23eab8835d28b1666dfd23c5a/tumblr_o5ztk5pNYf1rxyg66o3_250.jpg) boxes with words over this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to take care of it: http://jsfiddle.net/w0yL5njs/

1. Move your 'toggleMain w/ jQuery' code block to after your 'save/load' code block, so that the checkboxes will be pre-checked before the images' initial visibility are set.

   So the order of your `<script>` tags will be

   a) `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
   b) The script that uses jQuery.
   c) your save/load script that doesn't use jQuery.

   Actually, (b) and (c) can be in the same `<script>` but (a) must be separate.
2. Add `display:none` to the `<p>` containing the images.

   - Is that what `class="hidden"` was intended to do? You could add `.hidden { display: none; }` to your CSS...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove
if ($A_1_G.is(':checked')) {
toggleMain();
}      
// ADD
if ($A_1_G.is(':checked')) {
  $A_1_R_1.show();
}else{
  $A_1_R_1.hide();
}

//remove
if ($A_2_G.is(':checked')) {
toggleMain();
}

if ($A_2_G.is(':checked')) {
  $A_2_G.show();
}else{
 $A_2_G.hide();
}
```

Comment: toggle always applies from previous state, but when it is checked you need to show() always so go for show() instead of toggle()